# Show posts for default language if switched to language that has no posts added yet

Tags: multilingual, polylang

I have a site that uses Polylang plugin for languages. I have two languages, one default and another. All posts currently are added using default language, but when I switch to another language, nothing has been showing up. I would like in this case show content from default language instead and use another language when it will be added. Is it possible to make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to fallback to the default language using the Wordpress Polylang plugin. From https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fallback-to-default-language/ :

> This is not possible. There is no feature like this.
> The only way to do this is to “translate” the post and page but to add the default language content instead of the translated content. So technically the post and page is “translated” but the content is still the same.

However, [there seems to be a Wordpress plugin](https://github.com/helsingborg-stad/polylang-fallback) that does offer this functionality. The project is not very active, however. Perhaps you could pick up a clue on how to approach this problem from its source code.